# Traer dato que depende de dos columnas

Tags: excel, microsoft-office, office365, excel-2010, excel-2013

tengo los siguientes datos:

```
   _____A___ _|______B_______|_______C_____
1  |  CODIGO  |   CONCEPTO   |     VALOR
2  |  111222  |   con1       |     12000
3  |  111222  |   con2       |     11000
4  |  111222  |   con3       |      5000
5  |  333444  |   con1       |     10000
6  |  333444  |   con3       |      8000
7  |  555666  |   con1       |     70000
8  |  555666  |   con2       |     30000
9  |  555666  |   con4       |     60000
```

lo que quiero hacer es una nueva tabla de la siguiente manera(para con1):

```
  _____AA___________AB____________________________________
 1 |  CODIGO   |   con1    |   con2   |   con3   |   con4
 2 |  111222   |   =INDICE(A1:C8;COINCIDIR(AA2;A1:A8;0);COINCIDIR(AB1;B1:B8;0);3) 
 3 |  333444   |           |          |          |   
 4 |  555666   |           |          |          |
```

lo que quiero me daría de resultado esto:

```
  _____AA___________AB____________________________________
 1 |  CODIGO   |   con1    |   con2   |   con3   |   con4
 2 |  111222   |   12000   |          |          |   
 3 |  333444   |   10000   |          |          |   
 4 |  555666   |   70000   |          |          |
```

estuve tratando con la función INDICE y COINCIDIR

```
=INDICE(A1:C8;COINCIDIR(AA2;A1:48;0);COINCIDIR(AB1;C1:C8;0);3)
```

entonces para el con2 solo es cambiar la formula.

gracias por la atención.

Comment: quiero resaltar que los codigos ya los he filtrado, solo quiero capturar el valor dependiendo del codigo y el con(con1,con2...)

Comment: Porqué no usa una tabla dinámica para ello?

Answer (score 1):

La mejor manera para hacer esto es con una tabla dinámica. Agrupa los datos por CÓDIGO, y luego como columnas pon el campo CONCEPTO, y obtendrás lo que quieres:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien, si por cualquier razón necesitas hacerlo con fórmulas sí o sí, entonces te pongo otra solución. Ibas muy bien encaminado con COINCIDIR y con ÍNDICE, pero para que funcionasen, es mejor usarlos en forma matricial. Lo que yo he hecho es lo siguiente.

Lo primero, los datos de origen los he puesto en una tabla normal (no dinámica) que, en mi ejemplo, se llama T_ORIGEN.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto lo he hecho para que la fórmula matricial me resulte más sencilla, al usar rangos con nombres. Además, los rangos con nombres de una tabla son dinámicos y según vas metiendo datos en la tabla, se actualizan y así la fórmula siempre funciona.

Luego, el segundo paso sería crearte tu pequeño resumen, y meter la siguiente fórmula.

> **MUY IMPORTANTE:** Para que la fórmula funcione, es necesario que la metas en forma matricial, es decir, la escribes como siempre, y
>   presionas <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
>
> Sabrás si has metido la fórmula en forma matricial porque aparecerán
>   los símbolos **{** y **}** al principio y final de tu fórmula.

La fórmula es: `=SI.ERROR(INDICE(T_ORIGEN;COINCIDIR($F15&G$14;T_ORIGEN[CODIGO]&T_ORIGEN[CONCEPTO];0);COLUMNA(T_ORIGEN[[#Encabezados];[VALOR]]));"")`

He añadido un SI.ERROR para que, si no hay datos, muestre la celda en blanco, pero personalízalo con tus necesidades.

Cuando aplico la fórmula matricial, en mi resumen de datos obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi recomendación sería la tabla dinámica, pero desconozco tus necesidades, así que usa lo que te venga mejor.

Espero que esto te sirva y puedas adaptarlo a lo que necesites :)

Comment: muchas gracias por tu grandiosa respuesta, agradezco el tiempo que te has tomado para explicarme la solución, me ha servido de mucho y ya le estoy dando aplicación, la verdad casi nunca he trabajado con excel pero ya me toca, mil gracias

Comment: Me alegra mucho que te sirva. Por favor, marca la respuesta como correcta si te sirvió de ayuda, y así la pregunta quedará cerrada. :)